# how to interpret shape of array in numpy

Tags: numpy

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a1.shape # (3,)
a2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
a2.shape # (1, 3)

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2,3,4], [ 1,2,2]])
np.dot(a1,b) # array([ 8, 14, 17])
np.dot(a1,b) # array([[ 8, 14, 17]])
```

I have been thinking a1 as 'row vector' shaped as 1 by 3.
However shape is (3,).

Instead of this, the shape of a2 is (1,3) and it looks like more row vector.

Both (a1, a2) can be inner producted(np.dot()) and result in same figures. ( only except for shape )

Is there any difference to interpret these two?

Is it proper to interpret a1 as `row vector` ?

Comment: It's a 'vector', or in numpy terms a 1d array.  Look at the lists used to create them?  What is `[1,2,3]`?  what's that list's `len`?  What's the shape of `np.array(3)`?

Comment: the number of brackets determine shape of array. And I am confused what is different between a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]) and a2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3]]) except for shape. The difference is only the shape then I can use a2 instead of a1 ?

Comment: The difference is in the shape.  Experienced numpy users are happy with the (3,) shape, and don't use (1,3) (or (3,1)) unless it's really  needed.